# Html.ActionLink<> intellisense issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, intellisense

When i use any of the other strongly typed HTML helpers after typing for example

```
Html.Actionlink<HomeController>(x=>x.
```

This pops up intellisense on the methods that the HomeController class has. However for the example above, this does not happen. Only after inserting the link text (second parameter) and going back to the lambda expression does the intellisense work.

Are other people experiencing these issues?

**Update**
This issue is still in ASP.NET MVC RC

Answer (score 1):

You migth forget the controller type generic parameter:

```
Html.Actionlink<YourControllerType>(x=>x.
```

The controller type is needed here because views are not coupled to the controller. 
Views are coupled to the model only.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Intellisense in ASPX pages is flaky to say the least. I experienced the same as you described, as well as other unwanted effects. In some cases, Intellisense stops working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Until MVC there hasn't been a strong need to ASPX page intellisense for code.  I expect the VS team to work on this more with 2010, but until then you issues are normal at least from what I have experienced.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC does not contain a strongly typed action link method. Where did you get the method?

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing: I concur! ;-)

Comment: Microsoft.Web.Mvc futures dll